# Wordpress theme doesn't show set featured image button in custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am using the [Gonzo Wordpress theme](http://themeforest.net/item/gonzo-clean-responsive-wp-magazine/2415788) and I've noticed that in the custom post types I created is missing the button to add an image to the post.

In `functions.php` the support for thumbnails was activated:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

I tried adding an array of custom post types:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'article', 'cpt1', 'cpt2', 'cpt3'));
```

But it didn't change anything.

And when I register a custom post type there is the support for thumbnails:

```
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
```

Where can it be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the box for the featured image isn't hidden in screen options?

Answer (score 1):

Moving this line

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

to the bottom of the `functions.php` file actually solves the issue.

I'm not sure this is really a solution. Does it make sens putting it on the bottom? Is there maybe some parameter to pass to this or other function to change the execution order?